# Why does the simulator only have 12 rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My data has 50 entries. The simulator stops at 12. I don't understand.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    funcSectCount += 1
    let data = AppData.orgNames
    print("data.count=", data.count, "  func Section count=", funcSectCount)
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    funcRowCount += 1
    let data = AppData.orgNames
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: 
    indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    print("indexPath.row=", indexPath.row, "  func Row count=", funcRowCount)
    return cell
}
```

This as the final print for each function:

> **data.count= 50**   func Section count= 3 (curious, but minor)
>   indexPath.row= 11   func **Row count= 12**

Comment: Never rely on how many times and in what order any of the data source and delegate methods are called.

Answer (score 3):

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called by the table view each time it needs a new cell.

If only 12 cells are visible at a time then the table view initially needs only 12 cells so will ask for only 12 cells. You'd have to scroll before it would need to ask for more. It won't request cells until it needs them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is a great resource.

Comment: I was not clear. By Posting my feeble effort to determine if somehow the cell reuse was failing, I inadvertently allowed the emphasis to be misplaced. The real problem is this: in the simulator, when I try to scroll past the initial 12, will not do so. Depending on which device I use, there is one screen or even two along with a scrollbar, but the cells stop with the 12th. There is no scrolling beyond those originals which brings on new cells.

Comment: So the 12 go off screen, and then the table view fails to populate any further?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9a0n0chu21a60a/Screenshot%202017-05-11%2013.06.31.png?dl=0

Comment: the screenshot shows the last rows of the displayed screen. There is no further scrolling. Any attempt to do so results only in a bounce.

Answer (score 1):

So interestingly, even though the table is displaying correctly, the printout only reaches 12, and that happens regardless of how many cells you scroll to. Is that what you are finding? This is because you have 12 rows in a view, and the cells are reused, so you are not creating more cells but you are just reusing the 12 that you already have.

Comment: Not exactly. Both the screen and the printout only reach 12 (that may change with the Simulator version used. I believe I saw 13 once.)

Comment: do you mean that you only get 12-13 rows of your table displaying, and you can't scroll any further?